# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'avatar' on string using React Hooks/Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, react-context

I have passed down a state variable and function from my context file:

UserContext:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const UserContext = React.createContext();

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  var [userImages, setUserImages] = useState({
    avatar: '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/placeholder.jpg'
  });

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        userImages,
        setUserImages
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default UserContext;

export { UserProvider };
```

At this point `UserImages` is just an object with one prop i.e. `avatar`

This is my App which is being wrapped by the Provider (please disregard the redux implementation, I just wanted to try Context)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { UserProvider } from './UserContext';
import App from 'next/app';
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

import reduxStore from '../store/index';

import withReactRouter from '../with-react-router/with-react-router';


class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps
      ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
      : {};
    return { pageProps };
  }
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;

    return (
      <UserProvider>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate persistor={store.__PERSISTOR} loading={null}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </UserProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is one component i.e. `ImageUploader` I'd like to consume that state:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

import { Card, Icon, Image, Segment, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react';

import axios from 'axios';

function ImageUploader({ userData }) {
  var { avatar } = userData.userImages;
  var setUserAvatar = userData.setUserImages;

  function avatarUpdater(avatarPath) {
    var obj = {};
    return (obj.avatar = avatarPath);
  }

  console.log('setUserAvatar ', setUserAvatar);

  function fileUploader(e) {
    console.log('event fileUploader ', e);
    var imageFormObj = new FormData();

    console.log('e.target.files[0] ', e.target.files[0]);

    imageFormObj.append('imageName', 'multer-image-' + Date.now());
    imageFormObj.append('imageData', e.target.files[0]);
   setUserAvatar(
     avatarUpdater('/static/uploads/profile-avatars/' + URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])));

    axios
      .post(`/users/uploadmulter`, imageFormObj)
      .then(data => {
        if (data.data.success) {

          console.log('Image has been successfully uploaded using multer');

          console.log('avatar ', avatar);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error while uploading image using multer');
      });
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Segment>
        <Card fluid>
          <Image src={avatar} />
        </Card
       </Segment>
    </>
  );
}

export default ImageUploader;
```

Now in `ImageUploader` I have this function that I'm passing to `setUserAvatar`

```
function avatarUpdater(avatarPath) {
  return (userData.userImages.avatar = avatarPath);
}
```

Thinking this would work, but it doesn't I get back:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'avatar' on string '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/blob:http://localhost:8016/9039feda-f18b-43a7-b3a3-b7a32a7896f0'
    at avatarUpdater (ImageUploader.jsx?e724:14)
    at fileUploader (ImageUploader.jsx?e724:28)
    at onChange (ImageUploader.jsx?e724:63)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:347)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:397)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:454)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:468)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:600)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:622)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:725)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:733)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:707)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:750)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:881)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:5901)
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21657)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2348)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:5996)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6025)
avatarUpdater @ ImageUploader.jsx?e724:14
fileUploader @ ImageUploader.jsx?e724:27
onChange @ ImageUploader.jsx?e724:63
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:347
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:397
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:454
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:468
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:600
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:622
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:725
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:733
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:707
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:750
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:881
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:5901
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21657
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2348
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:5996
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6025
react-dom.development.js:487 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'avatar' on string '/static/uploads/profile-avatars/blob:http://localhost:8016/9039feda-f18b-43a7-b3a3-b7a32a7896f0'
    at avatarUpdater (ImageUploader.jsx?e724:14)
    at fileUploader (ImageUploader.jsx?e724:28)
    at onChange (ImageUploader.jsx?e724:63)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:347)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:397)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:454)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:468)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:600)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:622)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:725)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:733)
    at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:707)
    at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:750)
    at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:881)
    at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:5901)
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21657)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2348)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:5996)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6025)
```

Can anyone help me out figuring why the updater/dispatch is mentioning a blob when it should just be setting a path/string for the avatar in the component?

Answer (score 1):

it's bad practice to mutate state directly as you do `userData.userImages.avatar = avatarPath`. you should return next state value instead as `{ avatar: avatarPath }` for the `setUserAvatar`.

fwiw, the return evaluation `userData.userImages.avatar = avatarPath` results at `avatarPath` (string) being returned to `setUserAvatar`, which results at `userImages` being updated to a string rather than an object.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Think you can provide an example?

Comment: I see you are using classes also. A tip: hooks are alternatively to class based components, so you should choose if you want to implement the classic react with class based component or hooks which is focused on functional components. If you choose to classes, dont extend a class from another class, you always extend from React.Component. For extending functionality to a class you use HOC (High Order Components, while at hooks you create some custom hooks). Maybe it's time to sit back a little and try  to dig some fundamentals.

Comment: About the example I'm not sure entirely sure the scope of  it, you mean an update state example?